# Single User Table for multiple drupal sites

Tags: 7, users

I am having many drupal sites hosted in same server. But under different subdomain. I want a user registered in one site to be by default registered in other sites too. Optionally each site can have different profile fields. Is this possible?

Comment: Very possible - have you looked at / ruled out domain access module or the single sign module already? I've done this before but as a custom implementation sharing sessions across sites -- these modules would have been much easier way to achieve same ends.